# How can I check passwords against the 'haveibeenpwned Pwned Passwords' from PowerShell?

Tags: .net, api, powershell, security, httpwebrequest

I'd like to be able to use the [Pwned Passwords](https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v2#PwnedPasswords) list provided by [Troy Hunt's have I been pwned service](https://haveibeenpwned.com/).

The service is described in his *[Introducing 306 Million Freely Downloadable Pwned Passwords](https://www.troyhunt.com/introducing-306-million-freely-downloadable-pwned-passwords/)* blog post. The API uses an HTTP Not Found 404 status code to indicate when a password is not found in the list and a 200 to indicate that it has been found in the compromised list. This makes it difficult to consume via the [Invoke-WebRequest PowerShell Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest), which throws a WebException for 404.

Comment: Great question and answer, but why specifically did you want to not just catch the exception?

Comment: Curiosity about the .NET APIs really but also when testing for two outcomes, one of them doesn't feel like it should be 'exceptional' @MarkWragg

Answer (score 4):

The newer [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) allows you to make HTTP requests at a lower level and check the HttpStatusCode without dealing with exceptions for 404 as shown below.

```
function Test-CompromisedPassword {
    param([Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][string]$password)

    # Force assembly to be loaded
    Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Net.Http'    
    # By default PowerShell would use TLS 1.0 which is not supported by the API
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

    $baseUrl = "https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/pwnedpassword/{0}?originalPasswordIsAHash={1}"
    $url = $baseUrl -f $password,'false'

    $httpClient = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClient
    # User-Agent header must be set to call the API
    $httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "PowerShell script $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)")

    # HttpClient is only Async so use .Result to force the synchronous call
    $response = $httpClient.GetAsync($url).Result

    Write-Verbose "$password $([int]$response.StatusCode) $($response.StatusCode)"

    switch ([int]$response.StatusCode) {
        200 { $passwordFound = $true; break; }
        404 { $passwordFound = $false; break; }
        429 { throw "Rate limit exceeded" }
        default { throw "Not expected" + $response.StatusCode }
    }

    if ($response) { $response.Dispose() }
    if ($httpClient) { $httpClient.Dispose() }

    return $passwordFound
}
```

You can test this function as follows

```
Test-CompromisedPassword 'password' # Returns true to indicate password found
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1500 # Wait for the Rate limit time to expire
Test-CompromisedPassword ([Guid]::NewGuid()) # Returns false to indicate password not found
```